# How to compute scatterplots in R according to land cover?

Tags: r, raster

I have two rasters :

```
raster1
    class      : RasterLayer 
band       : 6  (of  6  bands)
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : XXXX
names      : GPP
values     : 0, 435.5 (min, max)

raster2
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : memory
names      : GPP
values     : 0, 506.4  (min, max)
```

I want to plot a scatterplot between these two rasters according to landcover. My raster file for  land cover is :

```
landcover
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 2803, 5303, 14864309  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.008333333, 0.008333333  (x, y)
extent     : 60.85, 105.0417, 15.95833, 39.31667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : XXXX 
names      : landuse
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
```

How can I plot a scatterplot between  raster1 and raster2 for the variable GPP, for the landcover for lets say evergreen forests which is represented by the value of 1 in the raster file of "landcover".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first step is to subset each raster by the land use you identified. Then you can plot them directly:

`plot(raster1[landcover==1],raster2[landcover==1])`

Comment: This code, seems to give the same scatterplot for different landcover classes. Can you kindly elaborate in "subset each raster by the land use you identified"? Does it mean raster1[landcover==1] what you wrote in the code above?

Comment: That is what you asked for "How can I plot a scatterplot between raster1 and raster2 for the variable GPP, for the landcover for lets say evergreen forests which is represented by the value of 1 in the raster file of "landcover"."